# I can access (red/write) the eeprom using i2ctransfer, but I can't instantiate an eeprom file in user space

Tags: i2c, eeprom

I have 2 Atmel EEPROMs - 24c128 - at addresses 0x0A and 0x0B.

```
sudo i2cdetect -y -r -a 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00: -- -- 02 03 -- -- -- -- -- -- 0a 0b -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU UU -- -- 
40: UU UU UU UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- UU UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I can read/write using i2c commands:

$ sudo i2ctransfer -y -f 1 w4@0x0a 0 0 **123 22**
$ sudo i2ctransfer -y -f 1 w2@0x0a 0 0 r10
**0x7b 0x16** 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff

I can't figure out how to see the eeprom as a file in order to be able to open, seek, write, read using file commands:

/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/1-000a$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    0 Mar 14 13:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root    0 Mar 14 13:51 ../
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 Mar 14 14:56 modalias
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 Mar 14 14:56 name
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Mar 14 14:56 of_node -> '../../../../firmware/devicetree/base/i2c@c240000/ub960@3C/link@2/ub953@42/sc9732cam_EEP@A'/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Mar 14 14:56 power/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Mar 14 13:51 subsystem -> ../../../../bus/i2c/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Mar 14 13:51 uevent

In the dtsi file:

> ```
>  EEP_NODE: EEP_NODE_NAME {
>   status = "okay";
>   compatible = "24c128","at24";
>   address-width = <16>;
>   #address-cells = <1>;
>   #size-cells = <0>;
>   reg = <0x0A>;
>   physical-addr = <0x52>;
>   pagesize = <64>;
>   size = <16384>;
>   has-eeprom = "1";  /* Enable EEPROM support */
>   node_name_alias = "EEP";
> ```
>
> };

[I used this post to try to instantiate eeprom in user space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499762/linux-instantiate-from-user-space-eeprom-new-device)

As user:
/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1$ **sudo echo 24c128 0xa > new_device**
-bash: new_device: Permission denied

As root:
root@mechi:/sys/devices/c240000.i2c/i2c-1# **sudo echo 24c128 0xa > new_device**
echo: write error: Invalid argument

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Mechi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I relied on the `d3_defconfig` file. I used:

```
sudo make linux-menuconfig
```

And chose in `Device Drivers/Misc./EEPROM` the `i2c` option. Now it works.

Comment: Please, take your time to fix the formatting of the Q and your A.